# Are Messages received by PacketListeners when application is temporarily killed?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

My App is using XMPP messaging, with the smack library, and I am registering a listener which is called when a message is received. The issue is, when my app goes in the background and is temporarily killed then will my listener be called or will I receive messages? If not then when my app comes alive then how to retrieve my messages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your Application get's temporary killed by Android, then the process is killed and all callbacks are gone (the whole process is gone).

As soon as Android's ActivityManager restarts the processes (usually after 5 seconds, but this time span may vary), you have to restore the state of the application: Load the global state (from persistent memory, from the `savedInstance` Bundle`, …), re-establish the connection and re-install all listeners.